# How to generate random int with given probability in python?

Tags: python

I want to output a random flag (either 0,1 or 2) based on given probabilities.

e.g.

```
flag = gen_flag(p0,p1,p2)
```

where `p0+p1+p2=1` and `p0`, `p1`, and `p2` indicate the probabilities generating flag 0,1, and 2 respectively.
So for example, `gen_flag(0.8,0.1,0.1)` would very likely output a zero.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: What have you tried? [Post a minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Suppose you had a random number between 0 and 1. How might you use that to decide which flag you want to output?

Comment: Did you actually look at the documentation? In how far does ``random.choices``'s ``weights`` not satisfy your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)

```
from random import choices

flag = choices([0,1,2], [p0, p1, p2])[0]
```

`p0` et al. don't have to sum to 1; they are normalized if they don't already.

`choices` always returns a list, even in the default case of choosing only 1 element from the set of possible flags.

Answer (score 0):

@Chepner has the best answer, but choices wasn't added to random until python 3.6. For earlier versions, I would take the inputs and make a 100 item list with the potential number of 0s, 1s, and 2s respectively. Then use the random module to pick an item.

```
import random

gen_flag(p0, p1, p2):
    myList = [0]*int(p0*100) + [1]*int(p1*100) + [2]*int(p2*100)
    return myList[random.randint(0,99)]
```